# Underscore not accepting in xml schema for email address

Tags: xml, regex, xsd

Hi I have created a schema and the following pattern to check for email id:

```
\w+([-+._]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*.
```

However it is not accepting email id's containing underscore like `bob_t@example.com`. Can you please modify this pattern so that it accepts `_` too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work (I removed some other apparent errors or idiosyncrasies):

```
\w[-+._\w]+@\w[-.\w]+\.\w[-.\w]+
```

however, be aware that whatever pattern you choose, you'll always exclude some valid email-addresses (the email address standard is very wide) while at the same time you may be including some invalid ones.

Comment: It would be nice if you accepted the answer after he bothered giving it!