# SQL Server - XML Validation: Invalid simple type value

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, xml, xsd

I'm trying to validate an XML input against an XML Schema in SQL Server 2005 and I get an error when validating the e-mail:

> Msg 6926, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>
> XML Validation: Invalid simple type value: 'john_doe@yahoo.com'. Location: /*:xxx[1]/*:yyy[1]/*:Email[1]

The email field is defined in the schema as:

```
 <xsd:simpleType name="EMailType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:pattern value="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
```

Every email address that matches the regexp is considered valid except for something with underscores in it (`johnDoe@yahoo.com` is OK, `john.doe@yahoo.com` is OK, but `john_doe@yahoo.com` is not).

If I remove the underscore the XML is validated.

I've tested my regexp (which is the one you can find on MSDN for validating emails) with various tools and they all say it's valid. But not SQL Server.

Why does it not validate underscores? Is there something special I must do in SQL Server?

Comment: Same problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973052/underscore-not-accepting-in-xml-schema-for-email-address

Comment: @Asken: that post treats an invalid regexp. My regexp is valid, SQL Server refuses to validate something with underscores in it (from what I could find out it has something to do with SQL injection since _ is a search wildcard)

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question but your regexp pattern does not allow for `_` right? At least that is the behavior using this in XMLSpy. So the error message from SQL Server is expected because `_` is not allowed or am I missing something?

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: \w takes care of _ (\w means word characters (letters, digits, and underscores)). Or maybe I'm missing something??!!

Comment: I've encountered an issue like this also... problems with underscores in the XML inside SQL Server. We were using it as delimiter for some keys and due to unfriendly fire under hostile environment (i.e. angry managers in a (late to) production application :D) we just hacked it by using something else as the separator. The entire app used underscores while this tiny bit used something else. Something I didn't like and never had the chance to see what was happening. Hope you get some answers on this. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a link about the issue with a workaround. http://www.agilior.pt/blogs/rodrigo.guerreiro/archive/2008/11/14/5965.aspx

Apparently `\w` should include the underscore and does so except when it comes to handling XSD schemas. So this is not a specific SQL Server problem. I have the exact same behavior when validating an XML using XMLSpy.

Comment: the link is a dead link :(

Comment: @Spence the link is fixed.

Comment: Link is dead again